# Is it possible to make screenshot of a panel window

Tags: screen-capture

For example I want to make a screenshot of a panel window "Fonts" in Mail. But I can't do it, because panel window is hidden when its parent app is not in foreground and to make screenshot of it, I need to open "Preview" first.

So, is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use shortcut <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to show the Font window

To take a screenshot using a manual rectangular selection, use <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>.

To take a screenshot using an automatic selection, press space as well.